Go 1.22 http mux: serve an handle and a FS on the same path
In a Go web application I have an embedded FS that contains either static files and templates files.
An index func func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) is working with parsing and executing a template.
How could I serve both on the / path?
GET / will serve index
GET/{anythingelse} will be served from FS
//go:embed assets
var staticFiles embed.FS

var staticFS = fs.FS(staticFiles)
htmlContent, _ := fs.Sub(staticFS, "assets")
fs := http.FileServer(http.FS(htmlContent))

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("GET /", fs)
mux.HandleFunc("GET /", index)


julienschmidt/httprouter has a router.NotFound. How can I do the same?

In Go 1.22, use the pattern /{$} to match the exact path / and the pattern / to match any path.
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("GET /{$}", index)
mux.Handle("GET /", fs)


Prior to Go 1.22, use an if statement in the index function:
//go:embed assets
var staticFiles embed.FS

var fs http.Handler

func index(w http.ReponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" { 
        fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return 
    }
    // insert original index code here 
}

func main() {
    staticFS := fs.FS(staticFiles)
    htmlContent, _ := fs.Sub(staticFS, "assets")
    fs = http.FileServer(http.FS(htmlContent))

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /", index)
    ...

